# How to group letters of alphabet and render to template in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vuejs data like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      alpha: [{
          artist: "Aa"
        }, {
          artist: "Az"
        },
        {
          artist: "Ab"
        },
        {
          artist: "Ba"
        },
        {
          artist: "Bb"
        },
        {
          artist: "Bc"
        },
        {
          artist: "Da"
        },
        {
          artist: "Db"
        }, {
          artist: "Dc"
        }, {
          artist: "Dx"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

What I want to do is simple to take the first letters of artist: `A, B, C, D` and create an array from them. After that I want to group all the artists by their index. So, the output would be:

```
A: (3) ["Aa", "Az", "Ab"]
B: (3) ["Ba", "Bb", "Bc"]
D: (4) ["Da", "Db", "Dc", "Dx"]
```

I can do this in my code, see below but the template isn't rendering it.

Here is the fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/fcas1wke/ for that works, you can see the console for the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array doesn't render because you are using non-numeric indexes on your array. This is described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52395924), but basically non-numeric indexes can't be iterated over so they won't appear in the output.

A more standard way to handle this would be to use an object instead of an array. Here's a working version of your component:

```js
Vue.component("alphabets", {
  props: ['data'],
  computed: {
    stack() {
      const result = {};
      this.data.forEach(function(element) {
        if (Array.isArray(result[element.artist[0]])) {
          result[element.artist[0]].push(element.artist);
        } else {
          result[element.artist[0]] = [element.artist];
        }
      });
      return result;
    },
  },
  template: `<div>{{ stack }}</div>`,
});
```

Note this version uses a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) instead of modifying the component's state on `created`.